# 1st Yr Probability: Need help understanding the difference between two problems (uniform circle and circle from two uniforms)

Tags: probability

I'm trying to understand the difference between problems 52 and 53 below. I do know how to calculate the answers which are $\frac{r}{\pi}$ and $r$ respectively. I believe the boundaries for both joint density functions are $Rcos(\theta) \in (0,1)$ and $Rsin(\theta) \in (0,1)$

**My questions**

1. In 53 are all points equally likely? I think no, distance from the origin is not. It feels like the probability of a radius close to 2 is "lower." I'm pretty sure all angles are equally likely.
2. In 52 the radius can be max 1. In 53 the radius can be from 0 to 2 correct? Since in 53 you can be farther from the origin, it seems weird to me that the joint density of 53 has a bigger height than 52... $\frac{r}{\pi} < r$. Since the circle can be twice as big, I would think the height would be less... generally bigger height means your "range" is less for uniforms (sorry if I'm butchering terms)

---

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: Note that the  natural interpretation of the sampling in Exer. 53 is uniform sampling of points from a square in the first quadrant.

Comment: The joint density of 6.53's $X,Y$ is $1$.

Comment: @poyea hmmm the book answer is $r$ and I also did it myself (get the inverse of the Jacobian)... is that not correct?

Comment: @hardmath is this right? -- so 52 is a uniform sampling of points from a circle and then changed to polar coordinate notation. 53 is a uniform sampling of points from a square which is then changed to polar coordinates and the result is a NONuniform sampling of points of a circle with radius 2?

Comment: In both problems we get different joint density functions for choice of Cartesian coordinates $x,y$ versus polar coordinates  $r,\theta$.

Comment: @hardmath that makes sense. Can you comment on the radius for 53? Would it be from 0 to 2?

Comment: The possible values for radius $r$ in Exer. 53 are $(0,\sqrt 2)$.  It is not a uniform distribution.

Comment: @hardmath ah good point, I'm an idiot.

Comment: I prefer to think we are all beginners at the game of math.